# Flutter voice and video call request

Tags: flutter, video, webrtc, voice

I am currently updating one of my flutter app with voice/video call features using WebRTC server. I am able to make voice call and video call.

Issue is - When sending the call it just opened up the camera in the client device but not waiting for the permission? Any idea what API/ what design, should I use, to ask and wait for the recipients acceptance for the call...

Basically questions are - 
1 - how can i wake up a recipient, if the app is in closed state
2- how can i just wait for the acceptance for my request..

Any flutter package or library reference would be a great help.

thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Agora is implementing some plugin to do this.

[https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine][1]